# How to Echo jQuery AJAX POST value of date in dialog box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datepicker

I am trying to echo the **POST** date value in a dialog box from the jQuery Datepicker from ajax. But its not working.

This is my jquery.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                     
onSelect: function(date) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"mypage.php",                           
        data : { date : date },
        success : function() {                                                          
                alert(date);                                    
                var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
                $('#dialog123').dialog({                           
                   modal: true                      
                });
        }
    });
}
```

});

Here i am getting clicked date value in alert.
This is my dialog.

```
<div id="dialog123" style="display:none;">                              
      <?php
        echo $_POST['date'];            
      ?>
</div>
```

Comment: tried alert(date); $('#dialog123').html(date);

Comment: ya i have tried.... but i need to echo in php

Comment: then you need to post your date value on page using js and then it will get

Comment: yes dear... see my code.. i have written  echo $_POST['date'] . and its not working..

Comment: Ignore my answer I misread your post let me do another example

Comment: Hold on, can you give me some more info on your setup here, if dialogue123 is on the same page as your date picker it'll never get set since $_POST is worked out when the page loads, if it's in mypage.php you won't be able to set it either as your success function  won't have access to dialogue123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return whatever your looking from from mypage.php:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                     
onSelect: function(date) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"mypage.php",                           
        data : { date : date },
        success : function(returned_data) {     
            // stick the returned data/html where ever you like                                                     

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. But $_POST['date'] which i have echoed inside dialog box , is it correct??

Comment: Yes that should work but its evaluated as the page is served so if its on the same page $_POST will be blank, with your ajax request your not doing anything with the output from mypage.php which is why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to get the posted date on mypage.php. Not really sure if your ajax called is on the same page but put them in anypage.php

So in anypage.php

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                     
        onSelect: function(date) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"mypage.php",                           
                        data : { date : date },
                        success : function(returned_data) {     
                            // stick the returned data/html where ever you like                                                     
                            alert(returned_data);
                       }
                     });
        }
  });
```

Then you can access the date in the mypage.php containing this code

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['date'];
    return;
?>
```

this should alert the date posted. Hope this could give you some idea.